# How to open iframe's links in default browser?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, youtube-iframe-api

I've a embeded YouTube player in a PhoneGap app.

When user clicks on the Youtube's logo he goes to YouTube's site (inside PhoneGap webview yet) and **can't** back to app.

I removed the `inappbrowser` plugin but Youtube still opening inside the app.

As a bad UX situation, Apple rejected the app too.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did u try _system in location

Comment: @KennethLi The link is inside of Youtube's player iframe, so I can't modify its content.

Comment: @TheoB I have the same problem - did you solve it?

Comment: @poornerd I had to prevent the user to click in the YT icon. Was a poor solution but Apple accepted.
`$('#ytplayer').contents().find('.ytp-scalable-icon-shrink').css('pointer-events', 'none')`

Answer (score 0):

Another poor solution, but more elegant.

Idea is the same: prevent opening of links from iframe with aim to prevent navigation of app-webview.

It can be done over sandbox directive of iframe, like described in this answer: [Prevent links in iframe to navigate/takeover cordova webview, especially in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26935485/4518246)

Comment: don't post links in answers as they can stop working